# Tracking Paste Events in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm looking for a way to detect Paste Events **after** they have occured in a WPF RichTextBox. 
I'm already using...

```
CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(rtb, OnPreviewExecutedCommand);
```

... for other functionality but since the handler executes before the command has been executed and ...

```
CommandManager.AddExecutedHandler(rtb, OnExecutedCommand);
```

... yields not a single invocation of the OnExecutedCommand handler I'm a but puzzled how to solve this problem. Ideally I would also like to to know (TextRange) what has changed in the document but that's optional.

The reason for this is that my RichTextBox is set to "IsDocumentEnabled=True" to enable clickable Hyperlinks in the FlowDocument. The hyperlinks needs to have a wired Click event in order to work in a FlowDocument. Now when the user copies and pastes content containing a Hyperlink, the copied version needs to be wired as well. That's why I need a way to track when structural changes are made to the document. I'm explaining this because maybe someone can suggest a more appropriate solution to solving the core problem.

Comment: Still need this?  For unrelated reasons I found a trick for doing this.